# Osmdroid (android 25): show offline Mapsforge file gives the error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field DEBUG_TILE_PROVIDERS

Tags: android, osmdroid

As step 1, online MAPNIK maps are shown after both Manifest.xml and Runtime permissions for read/write external resources.

As the next step, I want to show the map of an offline Mapsforge file using Osmdroid. The context is Android 25.

Can you suggest me a good version combination of Osmdroid, Osmbonuspack and Mapsforge?

The following code I use to show the offline Mapsforge file. The complete example is in a [Github project](https://github.com/johan974/osmdroid-mapsforge-demo). 1 File for selecting a file, 1 file for showing the file.

```
private void showMapsforgeFile( File mapFile) {
    File[] files = new File[1];
    files[0] = mapFile;
    MapsForgeTileSource.createInstance( this.getApplication());
    fromFiles = MapsForgeTileSource.createFromFiles( files);
    forge = new MapsForgeTileProvider( new SimpleRegisterReceiver( getBaseContext()), fromFiles);
    mapView.setTileProvider(forge);
    mapView.getController().setZoom( 9);
    GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(52.2222, 36.6123);
}
```

This gives (often) the next message:

> I/OsmDroid: Error downloading tile: /9/55/139
>               java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: **No field DEBUG_TILE_PROVIDERS of type Z in class
>   Lorg/osmdroid/tileprovider/constants/OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants**;
>   or its superclasses etc

I tried many combinations of versions of Osmdroid, Osmdroid and Mapsforge. For example (and I used a lot of other combinations ... as shown via jitpack.io, osmdroid releases and osmbonuspack releases. The error keeps the same.

```
compile 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.1'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.5'
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:5.5:release@aar'
compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.6.1'
compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map:0.6.1'
```

Comment: `D` means it's a debug message. That's not an error. Look at your logcat and post errors here.

Comment: Yep, understand. The thing is, it is repeating itself: read a tile, try to store the tile, cannot store the tile, read the same/other tile ... I added a few lines in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on github, you have mismatch of versions of osmdroid libraries. Set them all to the same version and you should be good to go. Offending reference: `osmdroid-mapsforge`.

https://github.com/johan974/osmdroid-mapsforge-demo/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L34

Edit:

Here's the working configuration

`compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.5'
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:5.6.5'
compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.6.1'
compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map:0.6.1'`

Note that it will log an error message related to rendering theme but it will render

There's also a few minor api differences which i fixed on my fork of your project and opened a pr.

Comment: SUPERB SUPERB. My app has now much more beautiful maps, with a max level of 20 (io 18). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Map is not rendering for me. It just shows yellow color.

Here is the log message.

Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed